# Convert Sage List of list of list to R list of list of list

Tags: r, list, sage, rdata

I have a sage list of list of list that is the result of some function applied over an R list of list of list (converted to sage format)

The code goes like this:

```
%r
my_r_list<-load("my_r_list.RData")

for d in range(D):
    for s in range(S):
        for c in range(C):
            my_sage_list[d][s][c] = ("my_r_list")[[d+1]][[s+1]][[c+1]]._sage_()
            output_my_sage_list[d][s][c] = some_function(my_sage_list[d][s][c])
```

I would like to convert `output_my_sage_list` back into an R list so as to save it into an `.RData` file

Documentation on interface Sage with R is mainly about going from R to Sage but not the other way around.[This question](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/9442/how-to-convert-sagemath-matrix-to-r-matrix/) concerns converting a sagemath matrix to R matrix using `r.matrix()' so i tried using 'r.list()' but with no luck. I also tried the simple`output_my_r_list = r(output_my_sage_list)`which gives no error but the output is not correct as doing`output_my_r_list[0][0]` doesn't give the last level of list but directly some values.

A reproducible code (bypassing the R to Sage part) would be:

```
    output_d = [[] for _ in range(9)]
    for d in range(9):
        output_s = [[] for _ in range(4)]
        output_d[d] = output_s
        for s in range(4):
            output_c = [[] for _ in range(2)]
            output_s[s] = output_c 
            for k in range(2):
                res = random()
                output_c[k] = res
```

I would like to convert `output_d` to an R list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is your statement

> I also tried the simple `output_my_r_list = r(output_my_sage_list)` which gives no error but the output is not correct as doing `output_my_r_list[0][0]` doesn't give the last level of list but directly some values.

Sage actually documents that it will make the list just one concatenated list, or more properly an R *vector*:

```
    sage: x = r([10.4,5.6,3.1,6.4,21.7]); x
    [1] 10.4  5.6  3.1  6.4 21.7

The following assignment creates a vector $y$ with 11 entries which
consists of two copies of $x$ with a 0 in between::

    sage: y = r([x,0,x]); y
    [1] 10.4  5.6  3.1  6.4 21.7  0.0 10.4  5.6  3.1  6.4 21.7
```

This is directly [modeled upon R usage](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Vectors-and-assignment), and presumably (via some nesting procedure) even just comes from it:

```
The further assignment

> y <- c(x, 0, x)

would create a vector y with 11 entries consisting of two copies of 
with a zero in the middle place.
```

So your beef is not exactly with Sage, but R, as (somehow) Sage gets the 'right' thing here.  Sage does this because  [here](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/interfaces/r.py#L810) it says

```
def _left_list_delim(self):
    return "c("
```

and then the R behavior follows as this is done recursively and it makes a vector of vectors.

A hack around this would be to return `"list("` there.  Another hack would be to try to use `r.eval("list(something)")` but I didn't experience a lot of success with this.

It would be nice to find a way to deal with this more easily, of course, and in the return direction Sage [attempts to take nested R stuff and keep it nested](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/interfaces/r.py#L1684) (with what success, I don't know).